# Repeatable configuration package

Tags: installation, automation, configuration

It's normal that a developer or a shop will spend several hours on each project running the same configuration options (for permalinks, SEO options, user roles, plugins that you always use etc.).

I'm coming from Drupal, where installation profiles have allowed me to preconfigure a set of configuration options that I can replicate across dozens of sites.

This has saved me and my clients hundreds of hours.

I now have an opportunity to do the same in WordPress. I'd like to create a script that installs WordPress, installs some plugins and sets some initial configuration options. This has the potential for useful time/cost savings when scaled across many sites.

Is this feasible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but very close.

There is a concept of 'dropin' plugins that exists primarily to override or add to core functions

The dropins will always load.

So one ftp's up wordpress including whatever plugin files you want that will create your default environment.  These should be in the top level wp_content folder.

I have one called **install.php** which overwrites the pluggable function

```
wp_install_defaults
```

with my own set of defaults (starting pages, default widgets, categories, taxonomies etc etc. ) It could load starting options for other plugins as well and possibly activate them.

Then you click the famous 5 min install (the 'script' you mention).  It installs wordpress and applies your custom options from the dropin plugin.

some brief information here:
http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/
http://bucketpress.com/drop-ins-plugins

Comment: This is exactly the kind of info I was looking for - thanks anmari!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a script per say, but I currently use the default-blog plugin to duplicate as many settings as I can from an original blog. This is handy when making a test site or a new instance of a site. Perhaps the plugin itself can shed some light on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a script, but I have a "Base" installation of WordPress were I have basic settings and plugins that I ALWAYS use. When I create a new site, I download all the website files and database. I use the [BackUpWordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress) to create a backup, then download. I also make sure to update all plugins to their most current version before creating a backup.

On the webhost, I create a new empty database, then import the downloaded database

Upload the website files to your web host.

In config.php, change the database options to reflect your new database.

Lastly, you need to change the URL of the site using one of the methods in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). I use the functions.php method.

From beginning to end, the entire process takes 10 minutes and you have EVERYTHING! You can even have all plugins setup how you prefer, pages you need on every site, such as contact, sitemap, privacy policy, etc.

I spent a long time trying to come up with the best method... This is the best I've found.