# Auto create pages on WordPress multi site register

Tags: multisite, pages

I'm creating a multi site and would like to have:

1. A few pages that are automatically created with the new site (at the moment only the default home and sample page are created with a new site, anyone know how that is being done?)
2. Even better but maby separate, a way to create pages in a form (on the register form or otherwise)

so that means optimally i want 4 pages (with content) made when a site is registered, and then a form asking them for the titles of 2 more pages that get created.

answers or ideas for either much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about multisite, however it usually works similarly to single site, so the following info may be useful:

There is a pluggable function (ie you write your own which will run instead of wp's function)

"wp_install_defaults"

Put your function in a 'dropin' plugin for install.php

and wp will use your function to create defaults instead of the wp defaults.

More info see:

[Repeatable configuration package](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30659/repeatable-configuration-package)
http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/

Comment: great, but still a little bit over my head...but maby i did it anyway!
I went in Function.php (in the theme) and added code from update.php (seems i dont have character allowance here to post in code but some is 
`
if ( is_multisite() )
  $first_page = get_site_option( 'first_page', $first_page );
 $first_post_guid = get_option('home') . '/?page_id=2';
 $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->posts, array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
`

Comment: sorry if my comment is inclear...just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this then dropping it in functions.php, or is that what you are ultimately  suggesting?

Comment: Tested with Multisite and works :o) :::: @user10580, there is no `functions.php` involved in this. The link about Must-use and Dropins plugins explains what you are missing. Take a look at this [Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75436/12615) as well.