# Populate content on install

Tags: installation

I would like to know if there's a way to populate a WordPress site with some dummy content while installation process is going on. Let's say a few sample pages, a fews posts, taxonomy and that's it.

I'm not sure if this is possible since I haven't found proper documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for another thing, just stumbled upon [this gem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34773/12615) by @anmari :)

You have to put a [Dropin plugin](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/) at the root of `wp-content`.

Should be named **`install.php`** and contain a new version of the pluggable function [`wp_install_defaults`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L93).

I used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4242948) for testing. And the only modification from the original function is the default category name and slug.

There's a [similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644474/1287812) at StackOverflow and Michael notice is worth copying:

> Since a default category of some kind is assumed, it's a good idea to create a least one category

Comment: This isn't correct brasofilo, dropins are not the same as putting custom install.php into `wp-content`

Comment: @Wyck, started to research, not much came up, and ended up opening a Question for that: [What constitutes a Drop-in Plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/75470/12615).

Comment: Ya it is a bit vague, especially dropping an `install.php` into `wp-config`, cheers.

Comment: To clarify I meant `mu-plugins`, they can both be considered "drop-ins".

Answer (score 3):

Use plugins like :

[WP DUMMY CONTENT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dummy-content/)

> Easy generation and deletion of blog posts, pages, and sub pages for developers. Full site structure in one click.

[DEMO DATA CREATOR](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demo-data-creator/)

> Demo Data Creator is a WordPress and BuddyPress plugin that allows a WordPress developer to create demo users, blogs, posts, comments and blogroll links.

Well and of course this plugins will be installed after installation is done!

Answer (score 2):

1.Your best bet is to use the theme unit test XML import after install, it can be found here:
https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml it includes images and tons of stuff.

- You need to go to Tools -> Import

2.The option to do it during install is to use brasofilo idea and create you own install. script by creating the following file: `wp-content/install.php`.

3.A third option is to use `mu-plugins` http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins which must be in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory by default (it can be changed) and can be named anything.

A better solution is to use a build system like wp-cli, phing, capistrano, etc, to run the install and include the needed data. For example I have a Phing script that deletes the default WP data on install and it would be easy to add data if you wanted to or drop in some `mu-plugins`or just do it right in the script.

In fact I might just go ahead and do this, it's a good idea.